# wait for string value change from null to other value

Tags: java, android

I have a class like below

```
public class Myclass {
   private static String mystring = null;
   public String process() {
      output = null; // reset the value
      try {
         mystring = longprocess();
      } catch (Exception e) {}
      return mystring;
   }
}
```

The problem with this is that I always get null value to my string method 'process'

How do I wait for the value of mystring change from null to something else and only then return the value?

**Note**: It is necessary to only return the variable 'mystring' inside method process and not use longprocess in return statement itself.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Maybe `longprocess()` throws an exception

Comment: is this long process starting a separate thread? otherwhise it could be an error you aren´t noticing due to the lack of exception handling

Comment: No longprocess is executing perfectly. The way I confirmed this is I logged the variable 'mystring' in a while loop, the variable is printed as null for sometime but it prints correct value after that time.

Comment: Add a print statement in the `catch` statement block, to see if `longprocess()` is indeed throwing an Exception.

Comment: It may be helpful to show the code in `longprocess()`

Comment: if your long process is in worker thread then use interface to getCallback

Comment: i doubt it is possible to give a real answer without knowing what longprocess is doing.

Comment: Ok, this problem is actually with my android app. The longprocess is actually a method which runs a command as root shell and returns its output

Comment: The method in question is
http://pastebin.com/uprTPX67

Comment: use `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: do one thing write `return myString; in try block` and `return "error"; in catch block` and see what you get. remove last return statement.

Comment: I do not receive any exception even with using 'Exception e'. Shabbir, removing last return statement and putting in try block gives compilation error of missing return statement

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provided with pastebin (BTW, why not include it in question?), it seems you return `output` string before it is assigned with real value.

Method `RootShell.getShell(true).add(cmd)` will execute provided command asynchronously, so you can't assign method's local variable `output` inside command's callback (you can, but actual assignment will happen after `return output;` statement, so you will always return `null` from your `longprocess()` method).

As a workaround I can suggest you to pass some kind of listener to your `longprocess()` method and assign `mystring` variable from this listener.